# Dotnet string searching ambiguity (netcore31 vs net47 vs roslyn)

Tags: c#, .net, string-search

I found out that in some cases string.IndexOf() returns -1 when searching for double line break \r\n\r\n when it is followed by 0xCC (204) byte sequence (could be also others, haven't checked). Below is a dotnetfiddle sample - it's possible to select compiler there. On netcore31 compiler the string is found always, on other compliers only when not followed by 0xCC sequence. Can anyone explain it?

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZMW7tL

**EDIT:** Same happens when I put 0xCB or 0xCD after last \r\n.

Source code of the fiddle:

```
using System;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var x = new byte[] { 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 13, 10, 13, 10, 204, 159, 67, 4 };
        var z = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x);
        Console.WriteLine(z);
        Console.WriteLine();
        var idx = z.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("index = " + idx);
        Console.WriteLine("=========================");
 
        var x1 = new byte[] { 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 13, 10, 13, 10, 5, 159, 67, 4 };
        var z1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x1);
        Console.WriteLine(z1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        var idx1 = z1.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("index modified = " + idx1);
        Console.WriteLine("=========================");
 
        var x2 = new byte[] { 13, 10, 13, 10, 204, 159 };
        var z2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(x2);
        Console.WriteLine(z2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        var idx2 = z2.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine("index short = " + idx2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's because of an encoding issue.  You have an array of bytes that are being decoded into a `string`, but 204 is not standard ASCII and therefore will use an encoding to convert it to a `char`.

Comment: @Neil I understand it is not an ASCII char, but I would expect .net to parse the incoming string "left to right" and once the matching substring is found its index is returned, no matter the subsequent characters. I do know that various encodings treat byte sequences differently, but I can't figure out exactly why the above sample fails. So I am after a more detailed explanation.

Comment: If you change it to `Encoding.ASCII` then it always works.  Which suggests your input bytes aren't valid UTF8.  I reckon it's undefined behaviour on the different compilers and 3.1 has a different (albeit correct in this case) undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's valid UTF-8. The character (encoded as two bytes in UTF-8) is a combining character, which combines with the character *before* it, so what you have is a `\n` with a combining `+` below. .NET Framework is comparing the combined character, not the separate code points.

Comment: @madreflection: so all 3 characters (203, 204, 205) are parts of combining characters? Can you link to some resources around this?

Comment: Ok, probably these: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768&number=128&names=-&utf8=0x

Comment: Yes, those. And even those are not complete "characters", just Unicode code points that combine with other code points to create characters.